# How to implement an ensemble of CNNs in Caffe?

Tags: caffe

I would like to train an ensemble of CNNs in Caffe.

1. What layers do I use to combine the softmax outputs to make decision by averaging? I am thinking perhaps adding a Concat layer followed by Pooling average layer in the TEST phase would do the trick?
2. Each CNN should see different region in the image. Do I use several Crop layers to do this i.e. a Crop layer for each network ?

Thanks.

Comment: do you train each component of the ensemble separately?

Comment: Ideally, I would like to train them jointly. I imagine that only one prototxt file will do, just different names for the corresponding layers e.g. for the first conv layer: "conv1_cnn1", "conv1_cnn2", "conv1_cnn3"...

Comment: but do you expect a single loss for all nets, or a loss per net (during training)?

Comment: it would be the total loss of all the nets